# How do I add a "Mute Sound" button in SpriteKit / Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, sprite-kit

I'm programming a little SpriteKit game and I want to add a mute button, so that you can hear your own music while playing my game. Currently I'm just stopping the audio playback for the scene the mute button is in (main menu). However my game still automatically stops the user music even if the audio playback is stopped. How can I prevent that?

Also, I'd like to pass the information that the mute button is pressed (located in the main menu) to my game scene, so that I can also mute the music there, how do I do that? 
Basically how do I pass a variable value from one scene to another?

Answer (score 1):

What I did a while ago is check if the iPod Player is working and give it priority over the game music. (ie. Check if iPod is playing to actually start game music, as ipod music player will usually overwrite you game's music if you are using AVAudioPlayer.

```
+ (bool) IsIpodPlaying{
    if ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying
        || [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying){
        NSLog(@"iPod IS playing");
        return true;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"iPod NOT playing");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Obviously you can do the same for your mute button. Ignore any action if iPod is playing, otherwise stop your game music.

To pass the information when the Mute button is pressed you can (in order of personal preference):

- Set your Menu scene as a delegate of your Game scene and create a method to enable or disable sounds (ie. `userDidEnableSound:` )
- Create a SoundControl singleton class that has the enable and disable sound methods and access them wherever you want.
- Send a notification using the `NSNotificationCenter` and wait for it in the menu.